# DataTriggers behaving oddly

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, datatrigger

### In brief:

Custom control `IconUC` has a property `IconType`. It's used to display part of a viewmodel that has a property called `IsProvider`. In a DataTemplate that uses `IconUC`, I use a Style trigger to try to change the value of `IconType` when `IsProvider` is `true`.

This appears not to be working, because different values of `IconType` should cause different vector graphics to be shown in `IconUC`, and I always see the same graphic.

### In detail:

I'm new to WPF and have been tasked with making some changes to an existing application.  I've been doing pretty well in so doing over the last three months but am stumped by this particular problem.

The existing scenario is that the application has a contact list.  A vector graphic is shown in front of each name in the list. However, a contact can upload a photo of themselves in which case, the photo should be shown rather than the vector graphic.  A custom photo is rendered via a `<ContentPresenter>`  The vector graphics are rendered via an IconUC control that inherits from UserControl.  It implements an IconType property that indicates which vector graphic to render.  `<DataTemplate.Triggers>` controls whether a vector graphic is displayed or the custom photo by setting the Visible Property to Collapsed or Visible on each control.  That has been working fine for the previous scenario but now I've been asked to make some changes.  Up to now the IconType does not change once the Contact List is loaded.

There will now be two lists appearing as a tabbed panel, both rendered by the same control.  One list is for patients the other list is for care providers.  I have both lists appearing as they should.  The other change is that, when no custom photo is provided, there are two possible vector graphics to show, one to show in front of patient names and another to show in front of provider names.  This is where things get weird.  I need to change the value of the IconType when the user navigates from one list to the other.  To do this I set up  a `<Style.Triggers>` for the IconUC control.  I created a property IsProvider that I bind the triggers to. This works WHEN I leave the IconUC Visibility property unset.  The ContentPresenter control gets overridden by the IconUC control so no custom photos are displayed.  If I set the value of the Visibility property to Collapsed on the IconUC, then the custom photos show like they're supposed but the IconUC always shows the patient vector graphic even when the IsProvider property returns "true".

I have verified that the IsProvider property is executed for each contact, irrespective of which list they appear in, so the IconType property is getting set but that isn't reflected when rendering is complete.

The DataTemplate's DataTriggers still work correctly for changing the visibility on both controls.

This is all happening in a DataTemplate which is consumed by a Dictionary which is consumed by a view.

If there is anybody that can help me understand how to solve this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the XAML from the DataTemplate:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ContactListItemDT">
    <Border BorderBrush="{DynamicResource CallListBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
        <Grid Height="40" Margin="4" IsHitTestVisible="True" Background="Transparent">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="8"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Visibility="{Binding EnabledSettings.IsPhotoVisible, Converter={MarkupExtensions:BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="CustomPhoto" Content="{Binding ContactRepresentative.Photo}" />
                <UserControls:IconUC x:Name="DefaultPhoto" 
                                 Background="{DynamicResource ThemeSilhouetteBackground}" 
                                 Foreground="{DynamicResource ThemeSilhouetteForeground}"
                                 Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <UserControls:IconUC.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControls:IconUC}">
                            <Setter Property="IconType" Value="Patient"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsProvider}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="IconType" Value="Provider"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </UserControls:IconUC.Style>
                </UserControls:IconUC>
            </Grid>
            <TextBlock Name="DisplayName" Text="{Binding DisplayName}" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="8,0,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource ThemeListItemTextBlockStyle}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Bold" FontSize="14"/>
            <TextBlock Name="DisplayDialString" Text="{Binding FormattedDialString}" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Padding="20,0,0,2" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="12" Style="{DynamicResource ThemeLightListItemTextBlockStyle}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ContactRepresentative}" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter TargetName="CustomPhoto" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Setter TargetName="DefaultPhoto" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Here is the IconUC class:

```
public partial class IconUC : UserControl
{
    public IconUC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public IconTypes IconType
    {
        get
        {
            return (IconTypes)GetValue(IconTypeProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(IconTypeProperty, value);
        }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IconType.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static DependencyProperty IconTypeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IconType", typeof(IconTypes), typeof(IconUC), new PropertyMetadata(IconTypes.Add, OnIconTypeChanged));

    private static void OnIconTypeChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        IconTypes iconType = (IconTypes)e.NewValue;
        IconUC iconUC = (IconUC)d;
        iconUC.Template = (ControlTemplate)iconUC.Resources[iconType.ToString() + "IconCT"];
    }



    public double OutlineThickness
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(OutlineThicknessProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OutlineThicknessProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for OutlineThickness.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OutlineThicknessProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("OutlineThickness", typeof(double), typeof(IconUC), new PropertyMetadata(0d));


}
```

The IsProvider is defined in a viewmodel named CallListItemVM.cs:

```
        public bool IsProvider
    {
        get
        {
            var callListItem = Managers.CallListManager.Instance.ContactList.FirstOrDefault((x) => { return x.DialString.Equals(dialString); });

            return String.Compare(((PhonebookContactVM)callListItem)?.CompanyName, "P", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != 0;

        }
    }
```

Sadly, the CompanyName containing a "P" in order to identify a patient is a hack I have to live with for the time being.  We're constrained from adding fields to the database.

Another thing I found is that there is  Silhouette property defined in a IconSettingsVM class.  If I change which IconType is referenced, it changes which vector graphic appears when there is no custom photo:

```
        public static IconSettingsVM Silhouette
    {
        get
        {
            return new IconSettingsVM(Views.Enumerations.IconTypes.Provider, "ThemeSilhouetteForeground", "ThemeSilhouetteBackground");
        }
    }
```

But that isn't very helpful to you.  This Silhouette property is used in multiple places but I can't draw a direct correlation to how it gets used by this DataTemplate.

Comment: It sounds like the problem may be in `IconUC`. Maybe its template. I could tell you if I saw that code.

Comment: Let me know if my "in brief" restatement of your question is incorrect.

Comment: If you just pasted a class definition into a comment, I'm going to commit suicide. Is that what you did? Consider your answer carefully. If after I'm gone, somebody tries to help you with this question, please consider pasting the code into your question where it can actually be read.

Comment: I tried but it was too long.  But no need to commit suicide.   I have added it to the main post.  Also, thanks for adding the brief restatement.

Comment: Thank you, Dar. Maybe I have more to live for than I realized. What happens if you put a breakpoint in `OnIconTypeChanged`? Does it hit that when the trigger (presumably) fires?

Comment: It only hits the breakpoint once at start up.  It never hits a breakpoint in the getter or setter for IcontType .

Comment: The conventional getter and setter for a dependency property are never used by XAML; they're an optional convenience for C# code to use. XAML will only call `SetValue(IconUC.IconTypeProperty, x)` and `GetValue(IconUC.IconTypeProperty)`. The value changed handler is the only reliable way to hook into a change in the value. Dependency properties are a different, parallel property mechanism.

Comment: Where is `IsProvider` defined? The binding in your `DataTrigger` assumes it's a property of the `DataContext` of the `IconUC` instance; I presume that's the `Contact` class.

Comment: We'll be getting deeper and deeper.  I'll add a couple more code segments in the original post.

Comment: Once an instance of `CallListItemVM` is created, does its `IsProvider` value ever change? If so, when that happens, it needs to raise its `PropertyChanged` event, with "IsProvider" for the `PropertyName` of the event args. Once the template is instantiated, that trigger will only fire in response to `PropertyChanged`/"IsProvider" coming from the DataContext.

Comment: Ah, that sounds like what I'm missing.  The value of IsProvider does change.  Sounds like I need to raise the PropertyChanged event. I'll give it a try.  Thank you.

Comment: Well, that wasn't it.  I misunderstood your question.  The only way IsProvider changes is when a new contact is loaded.  Ultimately, the problem I am having is that the OnIconTypeChanged() event is being called for each contact as it is loaded.  When I set a breakpoint there and watch what is happening, everything is happening exactly as desired.  So the iconUC.Template contains the correct ControlTemplate.  Despite the OnIconTypeChanged event being fired and setting the values correctly, what gets rendered does not change.

Comment: I solved my problem.  The more I looked at all the elements involved and particularly the ContentPresenter I started asking myself why we needed the UserControls:IconUC.  The ContentPresenter ought to be able to handle a vector graphic as well as a photo.  Once I approached it from that angle I found that I could remove both sets of data triggers and the IconUC elements altogether.  I modified the ContactRepresentative.Photo property to return either the custom photo or the appropriate vector graphic.  Fortunately, the underlying view models supported that change.